# pine-script how to know if last trade was a stop loss, wait n bars to open a new trade, how to reference id of last trade

Tags: pine-script

I have a trailing stop in Pine Script code.  I would like to the strategy to wait for n bars before being able to open a new trade if the last trade was a stop loss.  n could be an input.  The best way would be to check what the id of last trade.  If the id matches that of trade which would have been a stop, I can start counting bars.  How do I reference the id of the last trade? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's no mechanism to reference past trades by id. You can use something like this to calculate bars since the last loss, and test on that:

```
lastTradeResult = change(strategy.netprofit)
barsSinceLastLoss = barssince(lastTradeResult < 0)
```

Comment: This method would well if the stop is based off the entryprice, so thank you.  I usually use a trailing stop, so a trade could close with positive profit and a reversal could occur with a loss.
I could estimate the loss since the max profit of a trade, and assume that caused the stoploss but there is a small chance of error with that method.  
There is another difference which is that for trailing stop loss I use the strategy.exit function rather than strategy.entry or strategy.close.  Is there to reference if the last trade was closed due to .entry, .close or .exit? Thanks Benster

Comment: @PineCoders-Lucf  and what if I want to cancel only my next possible trade (my next true condition "entry_long"), if the last one was a loss?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following might work for you.  With each script iteration you can check if current bar's `losstrades` series variable has increased since the previous bar, hence letting you know that the last trade was a loss, and vice versa.

As far as getting an id of the last trade, you can track them and store them in `var` when you place a trade, to access at a later iteration.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Bars after loss", overlay=true)

var lastTradeId = "somerandomid"
var lastTradeWasLoss = false
barsWait = 5 // our N

if (strategy.losstrades[0] > strategy.losstrades[1])
    // last trade was a loss
    lastTradeWasLoss := true
    
if (strategy.wintrades[0] > strategy.wintrades[1])
    // successful trade, reset
    lastTradeWasLoss := false

// Check if strategy has no open position
isFlat = (strategy.position_size == 0)

// Check if strategy had no open position for more than N bars
if (isFlat and lastTradeWasLoss and barssince(ifFlat) > barsWait)
    // it's been more than N bars since last position was flat
    
    // store last trade id for later use
    lastTradeId := "somethingotherrandom"
    
    // execute trade
    strategy.entry(id=lastTradeId, ...)
```